# R Error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE is needed" when using if-statement in a for-loop

Tags: r

This error occured in a code chunk of stochastic simulation.The entire chunk is as:

```
set.seed(123)
X=10000
S=c()
r1=runif(X,min=0,max=1)
n=qbinom(r1,5,0.5) 
d<-c(0,1000,2000,3000)
u<-c(Inf,10000,20000,50000)
p<-c()
for(k in 1:4){
  S<-c()
  L<-c()
  for (i in 1:X){
    r2=runif(n[i],min = 0,max = 1)
    x=qpareto(r2,shape=2.5,scale=3000)
    z=c()
    for (j in 1:length(x)){
      if(x[j]<d[k]){z[j]=0}
    }
    S[i]=sum(x)
    L[i]=sum(z)
  }
  p[k]=length(L[L>10000])/length(S)
}
```

And the error **"missing value where TRUE/FALSE is needed"**  occurs in this part below.

```
    for (j in 1:length(x)){
      if(x[j]<d[k]){z[j]=0}
    }
```

To see what's wrong with it I tried out some similar code as below, and **it worked normally**.

```
for(k in 1:4){
   L=c()
   for(j in 1:3){
      x=runif(5,min=0,max=20000)
      for(i in 1:5){
        if(x[i]>d[k]){x[i]=x[i]-d[k]}
      }
    L[j]=sum(x)  
   }
   print(L)
}
```

So I guess the problem lies in the `length(x)`,but as a beginner I really have no idea why and how I can solve it...
Would be grateful for any suggestion! <3

Comment: Your code will stop when there is an error, with the current values of all the variables. So, when your code stops, what are the values of `x[j]` and `d[k]`?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need that inner loop. `for (j in 1:length(x)){if(x[j]<d[k]){z[j]=0}}` is a long (and inefficient) way to write `z = rep(NA, length(x)); z[x < d[k]] = 0`. But `z` seems to always be `NA` or `0` and the only thing you save is `sum(z)` without an `na.rm` argument, so I think you've got more problems...

Comment: For posterity, please provide the package from which `qpareto` is called.